# How do I link my screen keyboard, so it can fill out a mailchimp form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this keyboard that are meant to be used on a touch screen, like a info screen at the mall.

And the purpose is to fill out a mailchimp form. I've got it working with a textarea, but not with the e-mail input field.

Anyone can give me a clue on how to solve this?

Linke: http://onelan.grafikomudv.dk/keyboard/

Thanks!

Comment: You are using this keyboard instead of native device keyboard?

Comment: Yes, the info screen don't have a build-in keyboard, or a screen keyboard from the factory.